# Cómo mostrar imágenes de una carpeta usando PHP

Tags: php

[image: propiedades de la imagenes]Necesito mostrar las imágenes de una carpeta, pero no lo consigo. Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php
$directorio = opendir("C:wamp64/www/Andina/pics/");
while ($imagen = readdir($directorio)) {
    if (is_dir($imagen)) {
        echo $imagen."<br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        $completo = $directorio.$imagen;
        echo $imagen." - ".'<img src = $completo/>'."  -  " ;
        echo '<img src = "$directorio.$imagen"/>';
        echo "<br>" ;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Te sale algún error? o que es lo que pasa con este código

Comment: .
..
1000101251.png - -
1000101252.png - -
1000101253.png - -
1000101391.png - -
1000101392.png - -
1000101393.png - -
1000101401.png - -
1000101481.png - -
1000101482.png - -
1000101483.png - -
1000101501.png - -
1000101502.png - -
1000101503.png - -
1000101504.png - -
1000101505.png - -
1000101911.png - -
1000101912.png - -
1000101991.png - -
1000101992.png - -
1000102141.png - -
1000102142.png - -  Solo muestra el nombre de las imagenes, pero no las imagenes.

Comment: Para que las variables sean bien interpretadas por php, cambia las comillas simples por dobles:  echo $imagen." - "."<img src = '$completo'/>"."  -  " ; o construye la cadena de otra forma:  echo $imagen." - ".'<img src = '.$completo.'/>'."  -  " ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar glob es algo mas sencillo de utilizar al momento de listar los ficheros de una carpeta

```
<?php
    $directorio = "C:wamp64/www/Andina/pics/";

    function printImagesDir($dir){
        $files = glob($dir.'*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG}', GLOB_BRACE);
        foreach($files as $filename){
            $imgsrc = basename($filename);
            echo "<img src='{$dir}/{$imgsrc}' />";
        }        
    }

    printImagesDir($directorio);
?>
```

Comment: Gracias Victor, ya lo intente como tu amablemente me sugieres, y me muestra este mensaje: Warning: readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\wamp64\www\Andina\imgdir.php on line 5. Corregi $directorio por $dir, pero sigue mostrando el Warning. No muestra las imagenes.

Comment: Modifique mi respuesta, espero te ayude

Comment: Victor: Ya lo probe con tu ultimo aporte, pero me sale la pantalla en blanco. cuando trato de ver las caracteristicas de las imagenes, me aparecen como .png, pero en el reporte me dice que son tipo texto.

Comment: Eso no lo entiendo podrias mandar una captura por aqui?

Comment: Perdi tu primer aporte, donde me salian unos cuadros vacios en vez de las imagenes, y al pararme en cualquiera de ellos y dar click derecho, pedia la opcion de informacion de la imagen, y me salia en el recuadro superior imagen png, pero en la informacion de detalle abajo aparecia txt/html. Uso firefox. Capturo una imagen, pero no se como anexarla.

Comment: https://markdown.es/sintaxis-markdown/#imagenes

Comment: !.c:wamp64/www/Andina/pics/imagen.png

Comment: la tendrias que adjuntar en la pregunta

Comment: Victor, si me puedes reenviar por favor tu primer aporte, te puedo ilustrar claramente lo que te comente.

Comment: Ya adjunte la imagen a la pregunta.

Comment: Pero eso que muestras es lo que salio con el primer código o con este ultimo que puse? porque eso que sale ahi ya no parece el codigo que tengo en la respuesta

Comment: Con el primero me salio algo parecido, con el segundo no aparece ninguna imagen. eso lo logre con el codigo que te envie

Comment: Victor, se me presento una emergencia con mi nieta, debo salir para la clinica. Muchas gracia por tu ayuda y atencion, luego vere como podemos continuar el tema. Gracias.